# Derivative exists but is discontinuous at $0$

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} \mbox{ for } x \not= 0\\ 0 \mbox{ for } x=0 \end{cases}$

Do I use $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ to show that $f'(x)$ exists for all x?

Comment: You only need to use the limit definition to compute $f^{\prime}(0)$. For $x\neq 0$, $f^{\prime}(x)$ can be computed using the product rule and chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

When $x \neq 0$ your function is just $f(x) = x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$. This is clearly differentiable for all nonzero $x$, and you can find the derivative using the product rule and the chain rule.

It remains to find the derivative at $x = 0$. The easiest way to do this is to use the definition of the derivative at a point $x=a$:

$$
f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}
$$

In your case $a = 0$ and $f(0) = 0$, so this simplifies nicely.

Answer (score 0):

$$ f'(x) = 2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x) $$

for $x \neq 0$

Then show that there's continuity in the derivative at $x=0$ and it's smooth (you can take the second derivative if you want). You can use the squeeze theorem to show that your function is always bound above and below by two functions that pass through the origin, so the function itself must pass through the origin

Comment: No,  $f'$is not continuous at $0.$ That's the main point of the problem I would guess.